# Docker Machine: remove machines where STATE = Error or ERRORS is not None or DOCKER = Unknown

Tags: docker, docker-machine

To list active docker-machines on a local computer we can use `$docker-machine ls`.

Which gives the following:

`NAME    ACTIVE   DRIVER         STATE   URL   SWARM   DOCKER    ERRORS`

With each one populated by something, such as:

```
NAME                                       ACTIVE   DRIVER         STATE   URL   SWARM   DOCKER    ERRORS
api.horseshoe.v0.0.1.1570109766987.26    -        digitalocean   Error                 Unknown   GET https://api.digitalocean.com/v2/droplets/9999: 404 The resource you were accessing could not be found.
```

As just an example.

Now, to remove this manually I would do this:

`$ docker-machine rm -f api.horseshoe.v0.0.1.1570109766987.26`

However, I was wondering if there were a way to run a command which removes all of those machines where the following is true:

`STATE = Error || DOCKER = Unknown || ERRORS is not None`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use filter:

```
test=`docker-machine ls --filter STATE=Error --filter label=DOCKER=Unknown -q`
```

Use it:

`docker-machine rm -f $test`

All together:

```
`docker-machine rm -f $(docker-machine ls --filter STATE=Error --filter label=DOCKER=Unknown -q)`
```

you can also use the two commands in one step, I just wrote them so just as an example

see [this](https://docs.docker.com/machine/reference/ls/)

Comment: Hi, many thanks for this answer - however, I am receiving the following: `Unsupported filter key 'docker'`

Comment: I think that should be handled with labels

Comment: Ahhh, yes - `docker-machine ls --filter STATE=Error --filter label=DOCKER=Unknown -q` I'd add that to this answer...and I will accept as correct.